# Remote access via DataSnap to dynamic created TSQLConnection

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, datasnap

Delphi XE2 provides with DataSnap access to server-side connections from a client. The TSQLConnection driver "datasnap" has a property "ServerConnection", to specify a function that returns a server-side TDBXConnection. For example: ServerConnection='dsadmin.getConnection("FBCONNECTION")' returns the Firebird connection (listed in Data Explorer).

Instead of using the Data Explorer, I create my server sql connection during runtime. It should be possible to write my own MyFuncGetDatabase() serverside-function and set ServerConnection='MyFuncGetDatabase()'. But how can I implement a server-side function like MyFuncGetDatabase()? I have not found any hint at which place such methods must be implemented and/or registered.